# IntelliJ not recognizing Spring files in other modules

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

I have a Maven/ Spring project with about 15 submodules, all with their own Spring xml context files. Each module is an IntelliJ Idea module in this project (IntelliJ 15 on Windows, JRE 1.8.0_51)

Everything is executing correctly, but when I look at some of these Spring XML files in IntelliJ the reference shows up as red for some beans that point to other modules, and so things like ctrl-click and find references don't work for those beans.

Is there any way I can IntelliJ to get all of the Spring configuration files to recognize each other, without having to check in any new files to my project?

I have tried adding a new Spring context containing -all- of the Spring context files from every module, but still red

Comment: Were you ever able to get an answer to this?  I have the same issue and as you mention it doesn't affect the ability to run the project, but it would be nice for just clicking the spring bean to navigate right to it.

Comment: No, IntelliJ support told me to create the context I described above, but it did not work, and they have not responded to my subsequent inquiry